# Two implementations of Numpy fromfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, binary, fromfile

I am trying to update some legacy code that uses `np.fromfile` in a method. When I try searching the numpy source for this method I only find [np.core.records.fromfile](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.12.x/numpy/core/records.py#L721-L787), but when you search the docs you can find [np.fromfile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). Taking a look at these two methods you can see they have different kwargs which makes me feel like they are different methods altogether.

My questions are:

1) Where is the source for `np.fromfile` located?

2) Why are there two different functions under the same name? This can clearly get confusing if you aren't careful about the difference as the two behave differently. Specifically `np.core.records.fromfile` will raise errors if you try to read more bytes than a file contains while `np.fromfile` does not. You can find a minimal example below.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: my_bytes = b'\x04\x00\x00\x00\xac\x92\x01\x00\xb2\x91\x01'

In [3]: with open('test_file.itf', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(my_bytes)

In [4]: with open('test_file.itf', 'rb') as f:
            result = np.fromfile(f, 'int32', 5)

In [5]: result
Out [5]: 

In [6]: with open('test_file.itf', 'rb') as f:
            result = np.core.records.fromfile(f, 'int32', 5)
ValueError: Not enough bytes left in file for specified shape and type
```

Comment: Yes, you are linking to the source code for `np.core.records.fromfile`, which is specialized for dealing with record arrays.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am aware of that. Unfortunately this is the only implemented declaration of fromfile I can find in the source. I would like to know where I can find the source for `np.fromfile`

Comment: The essence of the `records` version is to create a recipient array of correct dtype and shape, and use binary file `readinto` method to load the bytes into its `.data` attribute.

Comment: The `core.records` stuff is a `numpy` backwater.  `structured arrays`, without the `records` overlay are more common,often produced by `genfromtxt` from `csv` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `help` on `np.fromfile` you will find something very... helpful:

```
Help on built-in function fromfile in module numpy.core.multiarray:

fromfile(...)
    fromfile(file, dtype=float, count=-1, sep='')

    Construct an array from data in a text or binary file.

    A highly efficient way of reading binary data with a known data-type,
    as well as parsing simply formatted text files.  Data written using the
    `tofile` method can be read using this function.
```

As far as I can tell, this is implemented in C and can be found [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.12.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L2026).

If you are trying to save and load binary data, you shouldn't use `np.fromfile` anymore. You should use `np.save` and `np.load` which will use a platform-independent binary format.

Comment: And to understand that `C` link you need to dig further and find the implementation for `PyArray_FromFile`.  `numpy` builtins are a mystery to mere mortals.

Comment: @hpaulj heh, yeah that is so typical for numpy. `array_some_function` written in C is essentially a wrapper around `PyArray_SomeFunction` written in C.... good luck tracking down `PyArray_SomeFunction`